# Read data from VIEW function on deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm trying to read some data from VIEW function on already deployed contract using my own smart contract. The function is standart "balanceOf(address)" of ERC20 token. I can read this data using etherscan web interface and no transaction required for this action, but I can't find the way to do the same using smart contract. I have this code (let's assume I have no source code of deployed smart contract, so I'm using abi.encode):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.15;

contract Test  {

   address dc = 0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D; //ropsten network ERC20 token address
   uint number;
   event Log(uint256 number, bytes b);


    function balanceOf(address _val) public {
      bool status;
      bytes memory b;
      (status, b) = dc.staticcall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("balanceOf(address)")), _val));
        emit Log(number, b);
    }}
```

but each time in Event Logs I see the same four numbers:
0
64
32
0

I tried to use staticcall, delegatedcall and call with no success. Can anyone suggest how can I read data from VIEW function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the function-signature, then you don't need the source code of the smart-contract.

For example:

```
contract IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address) public view returns (uint256);
}

contract Test {
    IERC20 dc = IERC20(0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D);

    function balanceOf(address _val) public view returns (uint256) {
        return dc.balanceOf(_val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works. But I don't understand now purpose of abi.encodePacked functions if we can just use function signature?

Comment: @kedcex: 1. It has many different usages, for example, you can call a function without knowing its exact return-type, and then reconstruct the returned value (using `b` in your example). 2. Please accept the answer (by clicking on the V next to it) if it has solved your problem.